# awk to transpose lines of a text file

Tags: awk

A .csv file that has lines like this:

```
20111205 010016287,1.236220,1.236440
```

It needs to read like this:

```
20111205 01:00:16.287,1.236220,1.236440
```

How do I do this in awk? Experimenting, I got this far. I need to do it in two passes I think. One sub to read the date&time field, and the next to change it.

```
awk -F, '{print;x=$1;sub(/.*=/,"",$1);}' data.csv
```

Comment: Why do you have an equals sign (`=`) in the RE you're trying to replace? Does your input file contain equals signs? If so please update your posted sample input to show that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use that `awk` command:

```
echo "20111205 010016287,1.236220,1.236440" | \
awk -F[\ \,] '{printf "%s %s:%s:%s.%s,%s,%s\n", \
$1,substr($2,1,2),substr($2,3,2),substr($2,5,2),substr($2,7,3),$3,$4}'
```

**Explanation:**

- `-F[\ \,]`: sets the delimiter to space and `,`
- `printf "%s %s:%s:%s.%s,%s,%s\n"`: format the output
- `substr($2,0,3)`: cuts the second firls (`$2`) in the desired pieces

Or use that `sed` command:

```
echo "20111205 010016287,1.236220,1.236440" | \
sed 's/\([0-9]\{8\}\) \([0-9]\{2\}\)\([0-9]\{2\}\)\([0-9]\{2\}\)\([0-9]\{3\}\)/\1 \2:\3:\4.\5/g'
```

**Explanation:**

- `[0-9]\{8\}`: first match a 8-digit pattern and save it as `\1`
- `[0-9]\{2\}...`: after a space match 3 times a 2-digit pattern and save them to `\2`, `\3` and `\4`
- `[0-9]\{3\}`: and at last match 3-digit pattern and save it as `\5`
- `\1 \2:\3:\4.\5`: format the output

Comment: One minor correction. In the awk solution it should be ($2, 0,2)

Answer (score 0):

sed is better suited to this job since it's a simple substitution on single lines:

```
$ sed -r 's/( ..)(..)(..)/\1:\2:\3./' file
20111205 01:00:16.287,1.236220,1.236440
```

but if you prefer here's GNU awk with gensub():

```
$ awk '{print gensub(/( ..)(..)(..)/,"\\1:\\2:\\3.","")}' file
20111205 01:00:16.287,1.236220,1.236440
```